# How can I chance the Dimension with numpy and reduce complexity?

Tags: numpy, numpy-ndarray

I recreated a deep learning network (Yolov3) and extracted a feature map after the prediction. This has the following dimensions (1, 13, 13, 3, 50). The dimensions 13x13 stand for the grid and the 3 for the RGB values. The 50 stand for the 50 different classes my model can predict.

Currently I am trying to reformat the feature maps for each class individually. That means, I try to create 50 arrays from the structure described above, which contain 3 arrays (each for RGB features) and should each contain the grid of 13x13.

What you have to consider is that the feature map contains the values of the 50 classes for each cell of the 13x13 grid.

Currently I have solved the problem with a for-loop that can only extract one class. So I have to ask myself if I can use Numpy for example with resize, transpose, reshape to set a better previous one.

```py
def extract_feature_maps(model_output, class_index):

    for row in model_output:
        feature_maps= [[], [], []]
        for column in row:
            tmp = [[], [], []]

            for three_dim in column:
                counter = 0
                for feature_map_tmp in three_dim:
                    feature_map_tmp_0 = feature_map_tmp[5:]

                    feature_number = feature_map_tmp_0[class_index]

                    tmp[counter].append(feature_number)
                    counter += 1
            feature_maps[0].append(tmp[0])
            feature_maps[1].append(tmp[1])
            feature_maps[2].append(tmp[2])
    return np.array(feature_maps[0]), np.array(feature_maps[1]), np.array(feature_maps[2])
```

As I said, I can currently only extract the feature map from one class in a very time consuming way. Is there a way to do this more clever?

Comment: `feature_map.transpose(0, 4, 3, 1, 2)`?

Comment: @jdehesa Thanks, I tried that code snipped and it worked. Can you also tell me what the Parameters mean? Thanks I`m so glad.

Comment: [`np.transpose`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.transpose.html) (or in this case the corresponding array method [`transpose`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.transpose.html#numpy-ndarray-transpose)) changes the order of the dimensions of an array. So after transposing, you get an array with the 0th dimension first, then the 4th, then the 3d and then the 1st and 2nd.